# Typo3 LTS9 and Piwigo

Tags: php, typo3

In my old Typo3 4.5 installation I had some folders in my public_html that contained isolated PHP structures, just like a complete Piwigo Gallery installation. domain.com/piwigo would have opened the Gallery.

Obviously this is and was not good practice. But now I have all these links to galleries in my pages and news articles. 
How can I integrate Piwigo in my LTS9 installation and still use the links?

Comment: Actually there should be no change here since URLs pointing to physically present directories are not processed by TYPO3. Did you change something about your `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an extension to integrate Piwigo into TYPO3. However you can run most other PHP projects next to TYPO3. TYPO3 will ignore directories not belonging to it. So there should be no reason why you can't keep Piwigo running the way it was and the links should keep working just fine.